# Align two tables together in a html code

Tags: html

I created a web page using just html and tables. My problem is my image is too big. I want to resize it and I want the motto beside it to align with the top of the question.

These is the code below.

- The first heading is in row1, cell12.
- The image is in row2, cell3.
- The motto is in row2, cell4.

The other lists are in different rows

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>CONFIRM HOOKUP SERVICES WEBPAGE<a href="wwww.confirmhookupservices.com">confirmhookupservices</a></title>
</head>

<body>
    <p bgcolor="blue">

    </p>
    <table width="90%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
        <tr bgcolor="red">
            <td width="200" valign="top">
                <h1 align="center"><big><b><i>CONFIRM HOOKUP SERVICES</i></b></big></h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="red">
            <td width="200" valign="center"><img src="C:\Users\EMIOLA\Documents\zlatan.jpg"><img align="left" valign="top" width="50" height="50"></td>
            <td width="100" valign="right" valign="top">
                <h3 align="right" valign="top"> Motto: We Put Smiles On The Faces Of Our Clients.</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <h2 align="center">WELCOME!</h2>
    <h3 align="left"><u>OUR SERVICES</u></h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href=http://www.confirmhookupservices.com/hookupwithfriends/ target="_blank">HOOKUP-FRIENDS</a></li>
        <li> <a href=http://www.confirmhookupservices.com/hookupforlovers/ target="_blank">HOOKUP-LOVERS</a></li>
        <li> <a href=http://www.confirmhookupservices.com/otherinterests/ target="_blank">HOOKUP-SPECIFY OTHER INTERESTS</a></li>
        <li> <a href=http://www.confirmhookupservices.com/help/ target="_blank">NEED HELP?</a> </li>

    </ul>
    <address>
        <p>You can also get through to us at:
            <ol>
                <li> 0803 2125 6777</li>
                <li>0903 3451 2222 </li>
                <li> 0802 2125 6777</li>
            </ol>
            <br>
            And you can also email us at:
            <a href="mailto:confirmhookupservices@yahoo.com">confirmhookupservices@yahoo.com</a>

        </p>

        <p>
            TERMS AND CONDITIONS APPLY-<a href=http://www.confirmhookupservices.com/termsandconditions/ target="_blank">T'S&C'S</a>
        </p>

    </address>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It seems you have used local path for image because of this, it is difficult to try and see the issue with your code. Can you try using any image of similar dimensions online? For better responsive behavior I would suggest to try Bootstrap CSS library.

Comment: Please can u edit the code and use any image at your disposal. i just wanna know how it works